# How tag creation is handled based on aggregated SE rep

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-creation

I'm registered on SuperUser, but not active - this is because most of my effort goes in other sites and because I'm pretty darned proficient as a computer user.

However I needed to post a question. But when I went to add a tag (specifically [live-id](/questions/tagged/live-id)) I violated this validation rule:

[image]

Honestly, I get it. I know the pain involved when you let people create tags willy-nilly. I'm not asking for über  privileges based on rep gained on other sites.

But surely it would be smart user experience to gauge my combined reputation<sup>1</sup>, transparently (to me) accept the tag, *but treat the new tag as a suggestion and place it into a review queue on that site*?

If the tag makes it through the review queue then I will be eligible for a [taxonomist badge](https://superuser.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist). Having a low site reputation doesn't mean I can't think up good tags, it should simply dictate *how* that tag creation proceeds.

Note that this is a user experience oriented question, I'm not looking to get pedantic over the actual tag (technically it should be `microsoft-live-id`, but that isn't in use either) - I'm more interested in having the tag treated as a proposal and reviewed rather than outright rejected.

<sup>1</sup> Looking at just raw aggregated rep won't be totally useful, I could just be a user with the 101 association rep on 20 different sites. Instead the algorithm should consider whether the user has a good level of reputation in at least one other site and/or whether the user is a ♦ moderator on another site.